# Global snackbar/dialog utils class in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to create a `GlobalMessageUtils` class that would open a material snackbar or dialog without having to pass the build context. The idea is that whenever there's any error (no network, bad request, etc) I am able to pop open a snackbar and relay the message to the user.Is there a concept of global `context`?

I was playing with the idea of making my `GlobalMessageUtils` class a singleton that takes in a build `context` and instantiate it at the `MaterialApp` level, but I haven't gotten this to work. Any body have any ideas? Is this even a good pattern in flutter? If not, how do you guys deal with error handling at a global level?

Comment: Did you found anything in this issue ??

Comment: @ZainSMJ I found a pattern to use instead of a global context. See my answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the BLOC pattern and Rxdart, I created a `UiErrorUtils` class

```
class UiErrorUtils {
 // opens snackbar
  void openSnackBar(BuildContext context, String message) async {
    await Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        content: Text(message),
      ),
    );
  }
  // subscribes to stream that triggers open snackbar
  void subscribeToSnackBarStream(BuildContext context, PublishSubject<String> stream){
    stream.listen((String message){
      openSnackBar(context, message);
    });
  }
}
```

In your StatefulWidget, you can use the context provided in the `initState` hook:

```
class WidgetThatUsesUIErrorUtils extends StatefulWidget {
  final UiErrorUtils uiErrorUtils;
  final  Bloc bloc;

  WidgetThatUsesUIErrorUtils({this.uiErrorUtils, this.bloc});

  WidgetThatUsesUIErrorUtils createState() => WidgetThatUsesUIErrorUtilsState(
        uiErrorUtils: uiErrorUtils,
        bloc: bloc,
      );
}

class WidgetThatUsesUIErrorUtilsState extends State<WidgetThatUsesUIErrorUtils> {
  final Bloc _bloc;
  final UiErrorUtils _uiErrorUtils;

  WidgetThatUsesUIErrorUtilsState({Bloc bloc, UiErrorUtils uiErrorUtils})
      : _bloc = bloc ?? Bloc(),
        _uiErrorUtils = uiErrorUtils ?? UiErrorUtils();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Subscribe to UI feedback streams from  provided _bloc
    _uiErrorUtils.subscribeToSnackBarStream(context, _bloc.snackBarSubject);

  }

}
```

BLOC

```
class Bloc extends BlocBase {
  // UI Feedback Subjects
  final PublishSubject<String> snackBarSubject = PublishSubject<String>();

  //  some function that gets data from network
  Future<bool> getDataRequest() async {
     try {
      // get request code here
      } catch(error) {
      this.snackBarSubject.add(error);
    }

  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    snackBarSubject?.close();
  }
}
```

Now your widget has subscribed to the bloc's snackBarStream.
So in your bloc whenever a request fails you can add the message to the snackBarStream and since your widget has subscribed via `UiErrorUtils` the snackbar will trigger with the message.

Answer (score 5):

1. define global variable e.g. inside `main.dart`

```
final GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState> rootScaffoldMessengerKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState>();
```

2. `MaterialApp` widget has `scaffoldMessengerKey` property so set this key to property

```
return MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  scaffoldMessengerKey: rootScaffoldMessengerKey,
  home: Scaffold(),
);
```

3. now you're able to show `SnackBar` from any place in app

```
rootScaffoldMessengerKey.currentState?.showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('some text')));
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It is working perfectly fine. If you are using bloc(cubit) pattern and you want to show snackbar for online and offline status, you can create Snackbars from your main.dart file.

Comment: This is nice but when using a dialog it shows on the main and dialog view - any idea how to show it in the dialog only, without passing the context around?

Answer (score 0):

For a Provider solution if you are using BaseWidget, then you can just create a base class method and use it everywhere you are using provider.

```
    class BaseWidget<T extends ChangeNotifier> extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget Function(BuildContext context, T model, Widget child) builder;
.
.
.

showToast(BuildContext context, String message, {int durationSeconds = 5}) {
  final ScaffoldMessengerState scaffoldMessenger =
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context);
  scaffoldMessenger.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: Text(message),
      duration: Duration(seconds: durationSeconds),
      action: SnackBarAction(
        label: 'HIDE',
        onPressed: () {
          scaffoldMessenger.hideCurrentSnackBar();
        },
      )));
}
```

Then just call it from your views.

```
.
.
.
showToast(context, "Factor Model Created Successfully",
          durationSeconds: 30);
          Navigator.pop(context, 'save');
```

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a Package that supports application wide message display.

EZ Flutter supports displaying a message to the user from anywhere inside the app with just one line of code. Global Messaging is handled with a BLOC and widget added as the body of a Scaffold.

Github : https://github.com/Ephenodrom/EZ-Flutter

```
dependencies:
  ez_flutter: ^0.2.0
```

#### Add the message wrapper

Add the [EzGlobalMessageWrapper](/lib/src/widgets/EzGlobalMessageWrapper.dart) as the body to a Scaffold.

```dart
Scaffold{
  appBar: ...
  body: EzGlobalMessageWrapper(
    MyWidget(
      ...
    )
  )
}
```

#### Add message to the bloc

Load the [EzMessageBloc](https://github.com/Ephenodrom/EZ-Flutter/tree/master/lib/src/bloc/blocs/EzMessageBloc.dart) via the [EzBlocProvider](https://github.com/Ephenodrom/EZ-Flutter/tree/master/lib/src/bloc/EzBlocProvider.dart) using the **get** method.

Add a [EzMessage](https://github.com/Ephenodrom/EZ-Flutter/tree/master/lib/src/model/EzMessage.dart) to the bloc. The supported [EzMessageTypes](https://github.com/Ephenodrom/EZ-Flutter/tree/master/lib/src/model/EzMessageType.dart) are :

- SUCCESS (default color : Colors.green)
- INFO (default color : Colors.blue)
- WARNING (default color : Colors.orange)
- ERROR (default color : Colors.red)

```dart
    EzBlocProvider.of<EzGlobalBloc>(context)
        .get<EzMessageBloc>(EzMessageBloc)
        .addition
        .add(EzMessage("This is a success message", EzMessageType.SUCCESS));
```

https://github.com/Ephenodrom/EZ-Flutter/blob/master/documentation/GLOBAL_MESSAGE.md